# Android Development: simple 2d graphic with sprite

Tags: android

Where can i learn simple simple 2d graphic. I came up with this simple idea(may be alot of these game) however i got a bucket sprite and ball sprites. the ball will randomly fall down and you have to catch them by rotate the phone.
I already got sprites(PNG) so were do i start. Canvas? wo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you read [through this series of tutorials](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html) to get you started with drawing 2D graphics on Android for games.